# Python - How to randomly choose items from hash?

Tags: python, dictionary, random

I have file elements.py where I have defined some elements

```
def get_random_element():
first = {
 a : 1,
 b : 2
}

second = {
 a : 2,
 b : 3,
 c : 4,
 d : 6,
 ....
}
...
return [ first, second, ... ]
```

In main python files, I am choosing random element from elements.py

```
from resources.elements import get_random_elements
...
element = random.choice(get_random_elements())
```

My problem is, that if it randomly choose second element (only second), I don't want there all items (a,b,c,d...), I want to choose it also randomly. So for example, if random generator takes second element, I want to also randomly choose its items e.g.:

```
a : 2
c : 4
d : 6
g : 9
...
```

Could someone help me, how to do it?

Comment: That thing is called a "dictionary" and it has a different syntax. So, please fix your code!

Comment: yeah, : instead =, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Randomize the random choice again!

```
import random

def get_random_element():
    first = dict(a=1, b=2)
    second = dict(a=2, b=3, c=4, d=6, )
    return [first, second]


# choose a random dict
choice = random.choice(get_random_element())
# choose some random keys, and generate the selected values
elements = {sample: choice.get(sample) for sample in random.sample(list(choice), random.randint(1, len(choice)))}
print(elements)
```

Comment: thank you, your piece of code works as I want. However, I don't understand this line
```{sample: choice.get(sample) for sample in random.sample(list(choice), random.randint(1, len(choice)))}``` Could you explain it please?

Comment: rebuild a dictionary with the samples collected randomly from the randomly chosen dict

Answer (score 0):

I have to make some assumptions on what you are asking but I will try to help.

basically what you are doing with

```
element = random.choice(get_random_elements())
```

is taking a random dictionary from the list of dictionaries you return from get_random_elements()

so you are randomly selecting a dictionary but I assume u want to take a random value of a random dictionary, now to achieve this you can do it in two ways:

**1st way:**

*in elements.py*

modify the return value of get_random_elements()

```
return random.choice([ first, second, ... ])
```

this way you are effectively returning a random dictionary from the function

make sure to import random in elements.py

*in main.py*

assuming you want to return a random *value* of the random dictionary:

```
element = random.choice(get_random_elements().values())
```

note that .values() returns a list containing the values of the dictionary

**2nd way:**

*in main.py*

```
element = random.choice(random.choice(get_random_elements()).values())
```

does the same thing as above but i would not recommand this since it doesnt maintain coherence with the function name and what you are effectively doing

Comment: I want to get random dictionary, which shouldn't contain all items, only several of them which will be randomly choosed again. So I would like to get random dictionary  e.g. second, with randomly choosed items e.g. b=4, e=5, x = 9 (missing a,c,d,f,....)